# How to set the width of an adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

Adaptive cards are fairly narrow in most channels - in web chat, for example. Is there any way to force the card to show the same width as the standard messages?

Comment: have you got a solution for this issue? I need to set `width` and `height` of the card!

Comment: The question is answered here. please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/66378082/6673637. All you need to do is add this. `{..., "type": "AdaptiveCard", "msTeams": { "width": "full" }, "body": [...]}`

Answer (score 2):

that's a pretty old question, however, many people come up with similar things frequently.

The answer is no, you can not change that. 
All visual aspects, width, height, font-styles, colors etc are controlled by the "host app" the host app is the channel eg MS Teams you are posting your card to.

See here for details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config

Only the hosting app can define things like width.