# Increase the width of Adaptive Card for MS Teams channel

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I have an Adaptive Card with 4 buttons on it, but the issue is that my 4th button is going over to the next line. I want to fit all the buttons in a single row, so is there any way i can increase the width of the Adaptive Card to align the buttons in a row.

I'm using bot framework v3 (C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct, afaik you can't increase the width of the adaptive card. Bear in mind, even if you could, it would give problems across devices - like it might fit fine on a desktop, but would give issues on a phone. As an alternative solution, can you logically split your buttons into two groups somehow (depending on what they do) and perhaps split them over two lines explicitly?

Comment: I think it is exactly the point of an ADAPTIVE card framework to look good on different devices and be responsive. At least give us an option to allow containers inside a card to be distributed on the x axis as well

Answer (score 29):

Add the below property to adaptive card to set the width to use the full window.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "msteams": { "width": "full" },
    "body": [...]
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I couldn't find the answer anywhere including MS documentation but this answer worked perfectly. This needs to be included in the docs. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This worked really great, You can add this object inside content block outside the body as below `"content": {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "msTeams": {
        "width": "full"
    },
    "body": [
        {}
    ]`

Comment: BTW, this is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card

Comment: FYI I don't know whether the api has changed so I'm not editing the answer, but as of 2023 and version 5 the 't' should not be capitalized in 'msteams'

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, [you cannot align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270145/button-alignment-in-adaptive-cards) your button side to side at this
>   moment. For button there is not such a property

. As you can see below:

[image]

Though you could align other element like `Input.Text` or `TextBlock` inside `ColumnSet`
but it doesn't support button inside.

See the screen shot below:

[image]

You could have a look more about [adaptive card property here](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/).

Answer (score 0):

The feature is coming soon to MS Teams. See here for reference: https://www.msfttoday.com/microsoft-teams-community-call-september-15-2020/

> Features coming soon include:
>
> - Full Width Adaptive Cards
> - Information Masking
> - Overflow Menu

Comment: Link URL is broken (looks like domain expired or site went away). For reference, this is why copying/pasting more information is a good idea, so there is no dependency on external resources that may break over time.